# Shrinking padding of node with label options

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-node

I am trying to implement command — let's name it `fn` — aimed to behave like `overset` command and underline the lower word with some curve. Doing this using TikZ. The lower word is made as node text, and the upper one — as node's label option. And because of that some additional padding is appearing like in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\tmpText}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fn}{ > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }{%
    {%
        \NewDocumentCommand{\tmpSubject}{mm}{%
            \IfValueT{##2}{\renewcommand{\tmpText}{##2}}
            \tikz[baseline=(Root.base)]{%
                \node[inner sep=0pt,
                      outer sep=0pt,
                      label={[yshift=-2,
                              font=\tiny\itshape] \tmpText}] (Root) {##1};
                \draw[line width=0.75]
                    let
                        \p1 = (Root.south west),
                        \p2 = (Root.south east)
                    in
                        (\x1, \y1 - 2) -- (\x2, \y2 - 2);
            }%
        }%
        \tmpSubject#1%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello:world}}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello}}
    \fbox{Hello}
}
\end{document}
```

Which is producing the following output:[image]

So, the main question is whether it ***is possible to correct paddings so that the output would be as follow (color is only for indicating desired area)***?[image] And of course, if the upper text is wider than lower one, width as well should be corrected to the wider text. Alas, could not find the answer myself neither on forum nor in TikZ.

And the additional question ***is it a good way  to define temporary commands inside another command in terms of performance?*** Like I defined `fn` in MWE? My main motivation of such nested macros is not to define function I do not directly need in main document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly set the `inner sep` to 0 for the node but forgot to do so for the label, which is also a node. Once you set it to 0 (or `0.5pt` for the optics) there, you no longer need the negative `yshift`. I also added a `%`, and marked the position with `<-`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\tmpText}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fn}{ > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }{%
    {%
        \NewDocumentCommand{\tmpSubject}{mm}{%
            \IfValueT{##2}{\renewcommand{\tmpText}{##2}}% <-
            \tikz[baseline=(Root.base)]{%
                \node[inner sep=0pt,
                      outer sep=0pt,
                      label={[inner sep=0.5pt,
                              font=\tiny\itshape] \tmpText}] (Root) {##1};
                \draw[line width=0.75]
                    let
                        \p1 = (Root.south west),
                        \p2 = (Root.south east)
                    in
                        (\x1, \y1 - 2) -- (\x2, \y2 - 2);
            }%
        }%
        \tmpSubject#1%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello:world}}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello}}
    \fbox{Hello}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without `calc` but with `line cap=rect`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\tmpText}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fn}{ > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }{%
    {%
        \NewDocumentCommand{\tmpSubject}{mm}{%
            \IfValueT{##2}{\renewcommand{\tmpText}{##2}}%
            \tikz[baseline=(Root.base)]{%
                \node[inner sep=0pt,
                      outer sep=0pt,
                      label={[inner sep=0.5pt,
                              font=\tiny\itshape] \tmpText}] (Root) {##1};
                \draw[line width=0.75,line cap=rect]
                        ([yshift=-2pt]Root.south west)--
                        ([yshift=-2pt]Root.south east);
            }%
        }%
        \tmpSubject#1%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello:world}}
    \fbox{\fn{Hello}}
    \fbox{Hello}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, a third version where we do not allow Ti*k*Z to choose the bounding box according to a path that has `line cap=rect`. To this end, I only insert a coordinate at the bottom and draw the line `overlay`, i.e. exclude it from the bounding box. This version comes with a comparison with plain `\fbox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\tmpText}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fn}{ > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { : } } m }{%
    {%
        \NewDocumentCommand{\tmpSubject}{mm}{%
            \IfValueT{##2}{\renewcommand{\tmpText}{##2}}%
            \tikz[baseline=(Root.base)]{%
                \node[inner sep=0pt,
                      outer sep=0pt,
                      label={[inner sep=0.5pt,
                              font=\tiny\itshape] \tmpText}] (Root) {##1};
                \path ([yshift=-2.375pt]Root.south west);             
                \draw[line width=0.75,overlay]
                        ([yshift=-2pt]Root.south west)--
                        ([yshift=-2pt]Root.south east);
            }%
        }%
        \tmpSubject#1%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|@{\,}l@{\,}|c|@{}l@{}|}
\fbox{\fn{Hello:world}} & \cmd{fd} with label & \fbox{\fn{Hello:world}}\\
\fbox{Hello}  & just \cmd{fbox} for comparison & \fbox{Hello}\\
\fbox{\fn{Hello}}  & \cmd{fd} without label & \fbox{\fn{Hello}} \\
\fbox{Hello}  & just \cmd{fbox} for comparison & \fbox{Hello}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also draw your attention to the `tikzmark` library, which comes with the command `\tikzmarknode`, which detect its ambient text (math mode vs. text mode etc.), which may be of use here.

Comment: Oh, this is great! @marmot, but what to do about the additional spaces on the left? I found out that one space comes from not putting `%` sign in the end on each line in command declaration, but still there is another inter-word space. Any thoughts why it might happen?

Comment: @robur Good catch! You need to add a `%` after `\IfValueT{##2}{\renewcommand{\tmpText}{##2}}` since otherwise a space gets inserted.

Comment: @mormot, but after adding `%` there is still one more space on the left, which I cannot explain. Could you give it a try, please?

Comment: @robur I added a third version. What you are (probably) referring to is the fact that Ti*k*Z computes the bounding box for lines with `line cap=rect`. One can switch this off.

Comment: @mormot, I cannot understand why, but I could not reproduce none of your output, alas with your exact codes — still some perceptible spacing! Why else could it be? I  can remove it directly with `hspace`, but it seems there is still a slight difference.

Comment: @robur I tested the third version and on my TeXLive 2019 installation I cannot see these gaps when compiled with `pdflatex`. I also added a zoomed screen shot in which I squeeze these `\fd`s and plain `\fbox`es without `\fd` between vertical lines, and even with the largest zoom available on `preview` I cannot see any gaps. Which installation/compiler are you using?